# How to change 'hover' function to 'on' function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use 'on' function instead of 'hover'. It's old code:

```
        $('.field').hover(
        function() 
        {
            old_value=$(this).text();
            item_id=$(this).attr('id');
            item=$(this).parent('td');
            new_value=(old_value=='Not translated') ? '' : old_value;

            $(this).empty(); 
            var field="<div id='save_button' class='btn btn-primary' style='float: right' href='#'>Save</div><form>"+
                "<div style='overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;'>"+
                "<input id='new_value' type='textarea' name='term' style='width: 100%;' value='"+new_value+"'/></div></form>";
            $(this).html(field);
        },
        function() 
        {

            $(this).empty();
            $(this).html(old_value);
        });
```

And it's new code:

```
        $('.field').on('hover',
        function(event) 
        {
            old_value=$(this).text();
            item_id=$(this).attr('id');
            item=$(this).parent('td');
            new_value=(old_value=='Not translated') ? '' : old_value;

            $(this).empty(); 
            var field="<div id='save_button' class='btn btn-primary' style='float: right' href='#'>Save</div><form>"+
                "<div style='overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;'>"+
                "<input id='new_value' type='textarea' name='term' style='width: 100%;' value='"+new_value+"'/></div></form>";
            $(this).html(field);
        },
        function(event) 
        {

            $(this).empty();
            $(this).html(old_value);
        });
```

Old code works good, but new one doesn't work (only mouseout function works). Please, tell me, where have I made a mistake? Thank you.

Comment: _"I need to use 'on' function instead of 'hover'"_ - Why? Nothing wrong with `.hover()`.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing to do is probably to bind to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` separately (which is just what `hover` does anyway). Here's the jQuery [source of the `.hover()` method](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.hover):

```
function (fnOver, fnOut) {
    return this.mouseenter(fnOver).mouseleave(fnOut || fnOver);
}
```

You can pass a map of event names to event handlers to [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('.field').on({
    mouseenter: function (event) {
        // First function passed to hover
    },
    mouseleave: function (event) {
        // Second function passed to hover
    }
});
```

But there is nothing wrong with `.hover()`, so you could just stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), "hover" pseudo-event name (used for "mouseenter mouseleave") is deprecated since v1.8 and you must use two event handlers instead of :

```
$('.field').on({mouseenter: function (e) { /* code */ },
                mouseleave: function (e) { /* code */ }
});
```

Comment: OP was referring to the [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) *method*, though, *not* the selector (a reference to which I can't even *find* in the jQuery API).

Comment: @DavidThomas - I think this answer is referring to the `hover` event name which is mentioned in the docs for `.on()` (and is deprecated as of 1.8), but you are right, that is not what the OP is referring to.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: *aaah...* that makes me less confused; thanks! =)